How to interpret Diffusion Maps for the iris dataset?
This might be a poor exercise but I'm trying to understand the methods of paper and if it makes sense to adapt my linear-based workflow with PCA to non-linear manifold methods; thought trying out diffusion maps would be worth a shot.
I'm trying to understand how to interpret the results from a diffusion map.  The iris dataset is definitely not the best toy dataset but thought I would still be able to see some relationships.
I have a few questions:

Why are the non-trivial eigenvalues in the negative? I understand why the first one is 0 is because the transition matrix P used in diffusion maps can be thought of as the transition matrix of a Markov chain. The leading eigenvalue of 1 corresponds to the stationary distribution of the Markov chain.
If I were to weight these eigenvalues by their "importance" (in PCA this would have been explained variance), would I skip the first eigenvector so I'm actually interpreting results in a D-1 space where D is the projected dimension?
Similarly to previous question, when I project my data back into this transformed space should I exclude the first dimension since the eigenvalue is 0?

Apologies if these questions are naive, I'm coming from microbial ecology and trying to understand the methods of a paper that I did not write.
Here's my code:
import pydiffmap as dm
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


X = pd.DataFrame({'sepal_length': {'iris_0': 5.1,   'iris_1': 4.9,   'iris_2': 4.7,   'iris_3': 4.6,   'iris_4': 5.0,   'iris_5': 5.4,   'iris_6': 4.6,   'iris_7': 5.0,   'iris_8': 4.4,   'iris_9': 4.9,   'iris_10': 5.4,   'iris_11': 4.8,   'iris_12': 4.8,   'iris_13': 4.3,   'iris_14': 5.8,   'iris_15': 5.7,   'iris_16': 5.4,   'iris_17': 5.1,   'iris_18': 5.7,   'iris_19': 5.1,   'iris_20': 5.4,   'iris_21': 5.1,   'iris_22': 4.6,   'iris_23': 5.1,   'iris_24': 4.8,   'iris_25': 5.0,   'iris_26': 5.0,   'iris_27': 5.2,   'iris_28': 5.2,   'iris_29': 4.7,   'iris_30': 4.8,   'iris_31': 5.4,   'iris_32': 5.2,   'iris_33': 5.5,   'iris_34': 4.9,   'iris_35': 5.0,   'iris_36': 5.5,   'iris_37': 4.9,   'iris_38': 4.4,   'iris_39': 5.1,   'iris_40': 5.0,   'iris_41': 4.5,   'iris_42': 4.4,   'iris_43': 5.0,   'iris_44': 5.1,   'iris_45': 4.8,   'iris_46': 5.1,   'iris_47': 4.6,   'iris_48': 5.3,   'iris_49': 5.0,   'iris_50': 7.0,   'iris_51': 6.4,   'iris_52': 6.9,   'iris_53': 5.5,   'iris_54': 6.5,   'iris_55': 5.7,   'iris_56': 6.3,   'iris_57': 4.9,   'iris_58': 6.6,   'iris_59': 5.2,   'iris_60': 5.0,   'iris_61': 5.9,   'iris_62': 6.0,   'iris_63': 6.1,   'iris_64': 5.6,   'iris_65': 6.7,   'iris_66': 5.6,   'iris_67': 5.8,   'iris_68': 6.2,   'iris_69': 5.6,   'iris_70': 5.9,   'iris_71': 6.1,   'iris_72': 6.3,   'iris_73': 6.1,   'iris_74': 6.4,   'iris_75': 6.6,   'iris_76': 6.8,   'iris_77': 6.7,   'iris_78': 6.0,   'iris_79': 5.7,   'iris_80': 5.5,   'iris_81': 5.5,   'iris_82': 5.8,   'iris_83': 6.0,   'iris_84': 5.4,   'iris_85': 6.0,   'iris_86': 6.7,   'iris_87': 6.3,   'iris_88': 5.6,   'iris_89': 5.5,   'iris_90': 5.5,   'iris_91': 6.1,   'iris_92': 5.8,   'iris_93': 5.0,   'iris_94': 5.6,   'iris_95': 5.7,   'iris_96': 5.7,   'iris_97': 6.2,   'iris_98': 5.1,   'iris_99': 5.7,   'iris_100': 6.3,   'iris_101': 5.8,   'iris_102': 7.1,   'iris_103': 6.3,   'iris_104': 6.5,   'iris_105': 7.6,   'iris_106': 4.9,   'iris_107': 7.3,   'iris_108': 6.7,   'iris_109': 7.2,   'iris_110': 6.5,   'iris_111': 6.4,   'iris_112': 6.8,   'iris_113': 5.7,   'iris_114': 5.8,   'iris_115': 6.4,   'iris_116': 6.5,   'iris_117': 7.7,   'iris_118': 7.7,   'iris_119': 6.0,   'iris_120': 6.9,   'iris_121': 5.6,   'iris_122': 7.7,   'iris_123': 6.3,   'iris_124': 6.7,   'iris_125': 7.2,   'iris_126': 6.2,   'iris_127': 6.1,   'iris_128': 6.4,   'iris_129': 7.2,   'iris_130': 7.4,   'iris_131': 7.9,   'iris_132': 6.4,   'iris_133': 6.3,   'iris_134': 6.1,   'iris_135': 7.7,   'iris_136': 6.3,   'iris_137': 6.4,   'iris_138': 6.0,   'iris_139': 6.9,   'iris_140': 6.7,   'iris_141': 6.9,   'iris_142': 5.8,   'iris_143': 6.8,   'iris_144': 6.7,   'iris_145': 6.7,   'iris_146': 6.3,   'iris_147': 6.5,   'iris_148': 6.2,   'iris_149': 5.9},  'sepal_width': {'iris_0': 3.5,   'iris_1': 3.0,   'iris_2': 3.2,   'iris_3': 3.1,   'iris_4': 3.6,   'iris_5': 3.9,   'iris_6': 3.4,   'iris_7': 3.4,   'iris_8': 2.9,   'iris_9': 3.1,   'iris_10': 3.7,   'iris_11': 3.4,   'iris_12': 3.0,   'iris_13': 3.0,   'iris_14': 4.0,   'iris_15': 4.4,   'iris_16': 3.9,   'iris_17': 3.5,   'iris_18': 3.8,   'iris_19': 3.8,   'iris_20': 3.4,   'iris_21': 3.7,   'iris_22': 3.6,   'iris_23': 3.3,   'iris_24': 3.4,   'iris_25': 3.0,   'iris_26': 3.4,   'iris_27': 3.5,   'iris_28': 3.4,   'iris_29': 3.2,   'iris_30': 3.1,   'iris_31': 3.4,   'iris_32': 4.1,   'iris_33': 4.2,   'iris_34': 3.1,   'iris_35': 3.2,   'iris_36': 3.5,   'iris_37': 3.6,   'iris_38': 3.0,   'iris_39': 3.4,   'iris_40': 3.5,   'iris_41': 2.3,   'iris_42': 3.2,   'iris_43': 3.5,   'iris_44': 3.8,   'iris_45': 3.0,   'iris_46': 3.8,   'iris_47': 3.2,   'iris_48': 3.7,   'iris_49': 3.3,   'iris_50': 3.2,   'iris_51': 3.2,   'iris_52': 3.1,   'iris_53': 2.3,   'iris_54': 2.8,   'iris_55': 2.8,   'iris_56': 3.3,   'iris_57': 2.4,   'iris_58': 2.9,   'iris_59': 2.7,   'iris_60': 2.0,   'iris_61': 3.0,   'iris_62': 2.2,   'iris_63': 2.9,   'iris_64': 2.9,   'iris_65': 3.1,   'iris_66': 3.0,   'iris_67': 2.7,   'iris_68': 2.2,   'iris_69': 2.5,   'iris_70': 3.2,   'iris_71': 2.8,   'iris_72': 2.5,   'iris_73': 2.8,   'iris_74': 2.9,   'iris_75': 3.0,   'iris_76': 2.8,   'iris_77': 3.0,   'iris_78': 2.9,   'iris_79': 2.6,   'iris_80': 2.4,   'iris_81': 2.4,   'iris_82': 2.7,   'iris_83': 2.7,   'iris_84': 3.0,   'iris_85': 3.4,   'iris_86': 3.1,   'iris_87': 2.3,   'iris_88': 3.0,   'iris_89': 2.5,   'iris_90': 2.6,   'iris_91': 3.0,   'iris_92': 2.6,   'iris_93': 2.3,   'iris_94': 2.7,   'iris_95': 3.0,   'iris_96': 2.9,   'iris_97': 2.9,   'iris_98': 2.5,   'iris_99': 2.8,   'iris_100': 3.3,   'iris_101': 2.7,   'iris_102': 3.0,   'iris_103': 2.9,   'iris_104': 3.0,   'iris_105': 3.0,   'iris_106': 2.5,   'iris_107': 2.9,   'iris_108': 2.5,   'iris_109': 3.6,   'iris_110': 3.2,   'iris_111': 2.7,   'iris_112': 3.0,   'iris_113': 2.5,   'iris_114': 2.8,   'iris_115': 3.2,   'iris_116': 3.0,   'iris_117': 3.8,   'iris_118': 2.6,   'iris_119': 2.2,   'iris_120': 3.2,   'iris_121': 2.8,   'iris_122': 2.8,   'iris_123': 2.7,   'iris_124': 3.3,   'iris_125': 3.2,   'iris_126': 2.8,   'iris_127': 3.0,   'iris_128': 2.8,   'iris_129': 3.0,   'iris_130': 2.8,   'iris_131': 3.8,   'iris_132': 2.8,   'iris_133': 2.8,   'iris_134': 2.6,   'iris_135': 3.0,   'iris_136': 3.4,   'iris_137': 3.1,   'iris_138': 3.0,   'iris_139': 3.1,   'iris_140': 3.1,   'iris_141': 3.1,   'iris_142': 2.7,   'iris_143': 3.2,   'iris_144': 3.3,   'iris_145': 3.0,   'iris_146': 2.5,   'iris_147': 3.0,   'iris_148': 3.4,   'iris_149': 3.0},  'petal_length': {'iris_0': 1.4,   'iris_1': 1.4,   'iris_2': 1.3,   'iris_3': 1.5,   'iris_4': 1.4,   'iris_5': 1.7,   'iris_6': 1.4,   'iris_7': 1.5,   'iris_8': 1.4,   'iris_9': 1.5,   'iris_10': 1.5,   'iris_11': 1.6,   'iris_12': 1.4,   'iris_13': 1.1,   'iris_14': 1.2,   'iris_15': 1.5,   'iris_16': 1.3,   'iris_17': 1.4,   'iris_18': 1.7,   'iris_19': 1.5,   'iris_20': 1.7,   'iris_21': 1.5,   'iris_22': 1.0,   'iris_23': 1.7,   'iris_24': 1.9,   'iris_25': 1.6,   'iris_26': 1.6,   'iris_27': 1.5,   'iris_28': 1.4,   'iris_29': 1.6,   'iris_30': 1.6,   'iris_31': 1.5,   'iris_32': 1.5,   'iris_33': 1.4,   'iris_34': 1.5,   'iris_35': 1.2,   'iris_36': 1.3,   'iris_37': 1.4,   'iris_38': 1.3,   'iris_39': 1.5,   'iris_40': 1.3,   'iris_41': 1.3,   'iris_42': 1.3,   'iris_43': 1.6,   'iris_44': 1.9,   'iris_45': 1.4,   'iris_46': 1.6,   'iris_47': 1.4,   'iris_48': 1.5,   'iris_49': 1.4,   'iris_50': 4.7,   'iris_51': 4.5,   'iris_52': 4.9,   'iris_53': 4.0,   'iris_54': 4.6,   'iris_55': 4.5,   'iris_56': 4.7,   'iris_57': 3.3,   'iris_58': 4.6,   'iris_59': 3.9,   'iris_60': 3.5,   'iris_61': 4.2,   'iris_62': 4.0,   'iris_63': 4.7,   'iris_64': 3.6,   'iris_65': 4.4,   'iris_66': 4.5,   'iris_67': 4.1,   'iris_68': 4.5,   'iris_69': 3.9,   'iris_70': 4.8,   'iris_71': 4.0,   'iris_72': 4.9,   'iris_73': 4.7,   'iris_74': 4.3,   'iris_75': 4.4,   'iris_76': 4.8,   'iris_77': 5.0,   'iris_78': 4.5,   'iris_79': 3.5,   'iris_80': 3.8,   'iris_81': 3.7,   'iris_82': 3.9,   'iris_83': 5.1,   'iris_84': 4.5,   'iris_85': 4.5,   'iris_86': 4.7,   'iris_87': 4.4,   'iris_88': 4.1,   'iris_89': 4.0,   'iris_90': 4.4,   'iris_91': 4.6,   'iris_92': 4.0,   'iris_93': 3.3,   'iris_94': 4.2,   'iris_95': 4.2,   'iris_96': 4.2,   'iris_97': 4.3,   'iris_98': 3.0,   'iris_99': 4.1,   'iris_100': 6.0,   'iris_101': 5.1,   'iris_102': 5.9,   'iris_103': 5.6,   'iris_104': 5.8,   'iris_105': 6.6,   'iris_106': 4.5,   'iris_107': 6.3,   'iris_108': 5.8,   'iris_109': 6.1,   'iris_110': 5.1,   'iris_111': 5.3,   'iris_112': 5.5,   'iris_113': 5.0,   'iris_114': 5.1,   'iris_115': 5.3,   'iris_116': 5.5,   'iris_117': 6.7,   'iris_118': 6.9,   'iris_119': 5.0,   'iris_120': 5.7,   'iris_121': 4.9,   'iris_122': 6.7,   'iris_123': 4.9,   'iris_124': 5.7,   'iris_125': 6.0,   'iris_126': 4.8,   'iris_127': 4.9,   'iris_128': 5.6,   'iris_129': 5.8,   'iris_130': 6.1,   'iris_131': 6.4,   'iris_132': 5.6,   'iris_133': 5.1,   'iris_134': 5.6,   'iris_135': 6.1,   'iris_136': 5.6,   'iris_137': 5.5,   'iris_138': 4.8,   'iris_139': 5.4,   'iris_140': 5.6,   'iris_141': 5.1,   'iris_142': 5.1,   'iris_143': 5.9,   'iris_144': 5.7,   'iris_145': 5.2,   'iris_146': 5.0,   'iris_147': 5.2,   'iris_148': 5.4,   'iris_149': 5.1},  'petal_width': {'iris_0': 0.2,   'iris_1': 0.2,   'iris_2': 0.2,   'iris_3': 0.2,   'iris_4': 0.2,   'iris_5': 0.4,   'iris_6': 0.3,   'iris_7': 0.2,   'iris_8': 0.2,   'iris_9': 0.1,   'iris_10': 0.2,   'iris_11': 0.2,   'iris_12': 0.1,   'iris_13': 0.1,   'iris_14': 0.2,   'iris_15': 0.4,   'iris_16': 0.4,   'iris_17': 0.3,   'iris_18': 0.3,   'iris_19': 0.3,   'iris_20': 0.2,   'iris_21': 0.4,   'iris_22': 0.2,   'iris_23': 0.5,   'iris_24': 0.2,   'iris_25': 0.2,   'iris_26': 0.4,   'iris_27': 0.2,   'iris_28': 0.2,   'iris_29': 0.2,   'iris_30': 0.2,   'iris_31': 0.4,   'iris_32': 0.1,   'iris_33': 0.2,   'iris_34': 0.2,   'iris_35': 0.2,   'iris_36': 0.2,   'iris_37': 0.1,   'iris_38': 0.2,   'iris_39': 0.2,   'iris_40': 0.3,   'iris_41': 0.3,   'iris_42': 0.2,   'iris_43': 0.6,   'iris_44': 0.4,   'iris_45': 0.3,   'iris_46': 0.2,   'iris_47': 0.2,   'iris_48': 0.2,   'iris_49': 0.2,   'iris_50': 1.4,   'iris_51': 1.5,   'iris_52': 1.5,   'iris_53': 1.3,   'iris_54': 1.5,   'iris_55': 1.3,   'iris_56': 1.6,   'iris_57': 1.0,   'iris_58': 1.3,   'iris_59': 1.4,   'iris_60': 1.0,   'iris_61': 1.5,   'iris_62': 1.0,   'iris_63': 1.4,   'iris_64': 1.3,   'iris_65': 1.4,   'iris_66': 1.5,   'iris_67': 1.0,   'iris_68': 1.5,   'iris_69': 1.1,   'iris_70': 1.8,   'iris_71': 1.3,   'iris_72': 1.5,   'iris_73': 1.2,   'iris_74': 1.3,   'iris_75': 1.4,   'iris_76': 1.4,   'iris_77': 1.7,   'iris_78': 1.5,   'iris_79': 1.0,   'iris_80': 1.1,   'iris_81': 1.0,   'iris_82': 1.2,   'iris_83': 1.6,   'iris_84': 1.5,   'iris_85': 1.6,   'iris_86': 1.5,   'iris_87': 1.3,   'iris_88': 1.3,   'iris_89': 1.3,   'iris_90': 1.2,   'iris_91': 1.4,   'iris_92': 1.2,   'iris_93': 1.0,   'iris_94': 1.3,   'iris_95': 1.2,   'iris_96': 1.3,   'iris_97': 1.3,   'iris_98': 1.1,   'iris_99': 1.3,   'iris_100': 2.5,   'iris_101': 1.9,   'iris_102': 2.1,   'iris_103': 1.8,   'iris_104': 2.2,   'iris_105': 2.1,   'iris_106': 1.7,   'iris_107': 1.8,   'iris_108': 1.8,   'iris_109': 2.5,   'iris_110': 2.0,   'iris_111': 1.9,   'iris_112': 2.1,   'iris_113': 2.0,   'iris_114': 2.4,   'iris_115': 2.3,   'iris_116': 1.8,   'iris_117': 2.2,   'iris_118': 2.3,   'iris_119': 1.5,   'iris_120': 2.3,   'iris_121': 2.0,   'iris_122': 2.0,   'iris_123': 1.8,   'iris_124': 2.1,   'iris_125': 1.8,   'iris_126': 1.8,   'iris_127': 1.8,   'iris_128': 2.1,   'iris_129': 1.6,   'iris_130': 1.9,   'iris_131': 2.0,   'iris_132': 2.2,   'iris_133': 1.5,   'iris_134': 1.4,   'iris_135': 2.3,   'iris_136': 2.4,   'iris_137': 1.8,   'iris_138': 1.8,   'iris_139': 2.1,   'iris_140': 2.4,   'iris_141': 2.3,   'iris_142': 1.9,   'iris_143': 2.3,   'iris_144': 2.5,   'iris_145': 2.3,   'iris_146': 1.9,   'iris_147': 2.0,   'iris_148': 2.3,   'iris_149': 1.8}})
y = pd.Series({'iris_0': 'setosa',  'iris_1': 'setosa',  'iris_2': 'setosa',  'iris_3': 'setosa',  'iris_4': 'setosa',  'iris_5': 'setosa',  'iris_6': 'setosa',  'iris_7': 'setosa',  'iris_8': 'setosa',  'iris_9': 'setosa',  'iris_10': 'setosa',  'iris_11': 'setosa',  'iris_12': 'setosa',  'iris_13': 'setosa',  'iris_14': 'setosa',  'iris_15': 'setosa',  'iris_16': 'setosa',  'iris_17': 'setosa',  'iris_18': 'setosa',  'iris_19': 'setosa',  'iris_20': 'setosa',  'iris_21': 'setosa',  'iris_22': 'setosa',  'iris_23': 'setosa',  'iris_24': 'setosa',  'iris_25': 'setosa',  'iris_26': 'setosa',  'iris_27': 'setosa',  'iris_28': 'setosa',  'iris_29': 'setosa',  'iris_30': 'setosa',  'iris_31': 'setosa',  'iris_32': 'setosa',  'iris_33': 'setosa',  'iris_34': 'setosa',  'iris_35': 'setosa',  'iris_36': 'setosa',  'iris_37': 'setosa',  'iris_38': 'setosa',  'iris_39': 'setosa',  'iris_40': 'setosa',  'iris_41': 'setosa',  'iris_42': 'setosa',  'iris_43': 'setosa',  'iris_44': 'setosa',  'iris_45': 'setosa',  'iris_46': 'setosa',  'iris_47': 'setosa',  'iris_48': 'setosa',  'iris_49': 'setosa',  'iris_50': 'versicolor',  'iris_51': 'versicolor',  'iris_52': 'versicolor',  'iris_53': 'versicolor',  'iris_54': 'versicolor',  'iris_55': 'versicolor',  'iris_56': 'versicolor',  'iris_57': 'versicolor',  'iris_58': 'versicolor',  'iris_59': 'versicolor',  'iris_60': 'versicolor',  'iris_61': 'versicolor',  'iris_62': 'versicolor',  'iris_63': 'versicolor',  'iris_64': 'versicolor',  'iris_65': 'versicolor',  'iris_66': 'versicolor',  'iris_67': 'versicolor',  'iris_68': 'versicolor',  'iris_69': 'versicolor',  'iris_70': 'versicolor',  'iris_71': 'versicolor',  'iris_72': 'versicolor',  'iris_73': 'versicolor',  'iris_74': 'versicolor',  'iris_75': 'versicolor',  'iris_76': 'versicolor',  'iris_77': 'versicolor',  'iris_78': 'versicolor',  'iris_79': 'versicolor',  'iris_80': 'versicolor',  'iris_81': 'versicolor',  'iris_82': 'versicolor',  'iris_83': 'versicolor',  'iris_84': 'versicolor',  'iris_85': 'versicolor',  'iris_86': 'versicolor',  'iris_87': 'versicolor',  'iris_88': 'versicolor',  'iris_89': 'versicolor',  'iris_90': 'versicolor',  'iris_91': 'versicolor',  'iris_92': 'versicolor',  'iris_93': 'versicolor',  'iris_94': 'versicolor',  'iris_95': 'versicolor',  'iris_96': 'versicolor',  'iris_97': 'versicolor',  'iris_98': 'versicolor',  'iris_99': 'versicolor',  'iris_100': 'virginica',  'iris_101': 'virginica',  'iris_102': 'virginica',  'iris_103': 'virginica',  'iris_104': 'virginica',  'iris_105': 'virginica',  'iris_106': 'virginica',  'iris_107': 'virginica',  'iris_108': 'virginica',  'iris_109': 'virginica',  'iris_110': 'virginica',  'iris_111': 'virginica',  'iris_112': 'virginica',  'iris_113': 'virginica',  'iris_114': 'virginica',  'iris_115': 'virginica',  'iris_116': 'virginica',  'iris_117': 'virginica',  'iris_118': 'virginica',  'iris_119': 'virginica',  'iris_120': 'virginica',  'iris_121': 'virginica',  'iris_122': 'virginica',  'iris_123': 'virginica',  'iris_124': 'virginica',  'iris_125': 'virginica',  'iris_126': 'virginica',  'iris_127': 'virginica',  'iris_128': 'virginica',  'iris_129': 'virginica',  'iris_130': 'virginica',  'iris_131': 'virginica',  'iris_132': 'virginica',  'iris_133': 'virginica',  'iris_134': 'virginica',  'iris_135': 'virginica',  'iris_136': 'virginica',  'iris_137': 'virginica',  'iris_138': 'virginica',  'iris_139': 'virginica',  'iris_140': 'virginica',  'iris_141': 'virginica',  'iris_142': 'virginica',  'iris_143': 'virginica',  'iris_144': 'virginica',  'iris_145': 'virginica',  'iris_146': 'virginica',  'iris_147': 'virginica',  'iris_148': 'virginica',  'iris_149': 'virginica'})
colors = pd.Series({'iris_0': '#66c2a5',  'iris_1': '#66c2a5',  'iris_2': '#66c2a5',  'iris_3': '#66c2a5',  'iris_4': '#66c2a5',  'iris_5': '#66c2a5',  'iris_6': '#66c2a5',  'iris_7': '#66c2a5',  'iris_8': '#66c2a5',  'iris_9': '#66c2a5',  'iris_10': '#66c2a5',  'iris_11': '#66c2a5',  'iris_12': '#66c2a5',  'iris_13': '#66c2a5',  'iris_14': '#66c2a5',  'iris_15': '#66c2a5',  'iris_16': '#66c2a5',  'iris_17': '#66c2a5',  'iris_18': '#66c2a5',  'iris_19': '#66c2a5',  'iris_20': '#66c2a5',  'iris_21': '#66c2a5',  'iris_22': '#66c2a5',  'iris_23': '#66c2a5',  'iris_24': '#66c2a5',  'iris_25': '#66c2a5',  'iris_26': '#66c2a5',  'iris_27': '#66c2a5',  'iris_28': '#66c2a5',  'iris_29': '#66c2a5',  'iris_30': '#66c2a5',  'iris_31': '#66c2a5',  'iris_32': '#66c2a5',  'iris_33': '#66c2a5',  'iris_34': '#66c2a5',  'iris_35': '#66c2a5',  'iris_36': '#66c2a5',  'iris_37': '#66c2a5',  'iris_38': '#66c2a5',  'iris_39': '#66c2a5',  'iris_40': '#66c2a5',  'iris_41': '#66c2a5',  'iris_42': '#66c2a5',  'iris_43': '#66c2a5',  'iris_44': '#66c2a5',  'iris_45': '#66c2a5',  'iris_46': '#66c2a5',  'iris_47': '#66c2a5',  'iris_48': '#66c2a5',  'iris_49': '#66c2a5',  'iris_50': '#fc8d62',  'iris_51': '#fc8d62',  'iris_52': '#fc8d62',  'iris_53': '#fc8d62',  'iris_54': '#fc8d62',  'iris_55': '#fc8d62',  'iris_56': '#fc8d62',  'iris_57': '#fc8d62',  'iris_58': '#fc8d62',  'iris_59': '#fc8d62',  'iris_60': '#fc8d62',  'iris_61': '#fc8d62',  'iris_62': '#fc8d62',  'iris_63': '#fc8d62',  'iris_64': '#fc8d62',  'iris_65': '#fc8d62',  'iris_66': '#fc8d62',  'iris_67': '#fc8d62',  'iris_68': '#fc8d62',  'iris_69': '#fc8d62',  'iris_70': '#fc8d62',  'iris_71': '#fc8d62',  'iris_72': '#fc8d62',  'iris_73': '#fc8d62',  'iris_74': '#fc8d62',  'iris_75': '#fc8d62',  'iris_76': '#fc8d62',  'iris_77': '#fc8d62',  'iris_78': '#fc8d62',  'iris_79': '#fc8d62',  'iris_80': '#fc8d62',  'iris_81': '#fc8d62',  'iris_82': '#fc8d62',  'iris_83': '#fc8d62',  'iris_84': '#fc8d62',  'iris_85': '#fc8d62',  'iris_86': '#fc8d62',  'iris_87': '#fc8d62',  'iris_88': '#fc8d62',  'iris_89': '#fc8d62',  'iris_90': '#fc8d62',  'iris_91': '#fc8d62',  'iris_92': '#fc8d62',  'iris_93': '#fc8d62',  'iris_94': '#fc8d62',  'iris_95': '#fc8d62',  'iris_96': '#fc8d62',  'iris_97': '#fc8d62',  'iris_98': '#fc8d62',  'iris_99': '#fc8d62',  'iris_100': '#8da0cb',  'iris_101': '#8da0cb',  'iris_102': '#8da0cb',  'iris_103': '#8da0cb',  'iris_104': '#8da0cb',  'iris_105': '#8da0cb',  'iris_106': '#8da0cb',  'iris_107': '#8da0cb',  'iris_108': '#8da0cb',  'iris_109': '#8da0cb',  'iris_110': '#8da0cb',  'iris_111': '#8da0cb',  'iris_112': '#8da0cb',  'iris_113': '#8da0cb',  'iris_114': '#8da0cb',  'iris_115': '#8da0cb',  'iris_116': '#8da0cb',  'iris_117': '#8da0cb',  'iris_118': '#8da0cb',  'iris_119': '#8da0cb',  'iris_120': '#8da0cb',  'iris_121': '#8da0cb',  'iris_122': '#8da0cb',  'iris_123': '#8da0cb',  'iris_124': '#8da0cb',  'iris_125': '#8da0cb',  'iris_126': '#8da0cb',  'iris_127': '#8da0cb',  'iris_128': '#8da0cb',  'iris_129': '#8da0cb',  'iris_130': '#8da0cb',  'iris_131': '#8da0cb',  'iris_132': '#8da0cb',  'iris_133': '#8da0cb',  'iris_134': '#8da0cb',  'iris_135': '#8da0cb',  'iris_136': '#8da0cb',  'iris_137': '#8da0cb',  'iris_138': '#8da0cb',  'iris_139': '#8da0cb',  'iris_140': '#8da0cb',  'iris_141': '#8da0cb',  'iris_142': '#8da0cb',  'iris_143': '#8da0cb',  'iris_144': '#8da0cb',  'iris_145': '#8da0cb',  'iris_146': '#8da0cb',  'iris_147': '#8da0cb',  'iris_148': '#8da0cb',  'iris_149': '#8da0cb'})

n_neighbors = 10
n_evecs = min(X.shape)
# n_evecs = 2
model = dm.diffusion_map.DiffusionMap.from_sklearn(n_evecs=n_evecs, k=n_neighbors)
model.fit(X)
X_transformed = pd.DataFrame(model.transform(X), index=X.index)
X_transformed.columns = X_transformed.columns.map(lambda j: f"DM{j + 1}")
with plt.style.context('seaborn-v0_8-whitegrid'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
    x = "DM1"
    y = "DM2"
    ax.scatter(data=X_transformed, x=x, y=y, c=colors.values)
    ax.set_xlabel(x)
    ax.set_ylabel(y)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,1))
    pd.Series(model.evals, index=X_transformed.columns).plot(kind="bar", ax=ax)
    ax.set_ylabel("Eigenvalue")
    


